# Profile picture only displays black box with an "X" inside

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a profile page where user can upload a profile picture. The problem I a having is that when the status is changed from 1 to 0 the image changes from a default profile image to a small black box with an "x" in it. Everything else works fine. I thought it might be the css but it is not. If anyone can assist, it would greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Profile.php:

```
<?php
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileImg WHERE id='$id'";
        $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
        while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {
            echo "<div class='userProfileImage'>";
                if ($rowImg['status'] == 0 ) {
                    echo "<img src='images/profile".$id.".jpg'>";
                } else {
                    echo "<img src='images/profile_default.jpg'>";
                }
                echo "<p>".$row['first']."</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }   
}       else {
            echo "There are no users yet!";
        }
```

uploadProfile.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../dbh.php';
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$userID = $id;



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileERROR = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'mov', 'mpeg4', 'mp4', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mpegps', 'flv', '3gpp', 'webm');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileERROR === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 500000) {
                $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = '../uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                $sql = "UPDATE profileImg SET status=0 WHERE id='$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                header("Location: ../profile.php?id=$userID");
            } else {
                echo "Your file is too large";
            }

        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading your file";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Well that either means you managed to store a broken image to begin with, or  - more likely - you did not output the path to it correctly. So start by checking the latter.

Comment: will be diferent extensions? "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt in save and $id.".jpsg" in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are being uploaded to uploads as line below

```
$fileDestination = '../uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
```

and img src is
  `echo "<img src='images/profile".$id.".jpg'>";`

Please update you code.

**Edit:**  you are allowing multiple extensions to be uploaded and on profile.php single extension is used to load the picture.

Comment: I will do that. thanks much. Can't believe I missed the paths being different.  I will fix the extensions as well. thanks again.